# strange result form stats.mannwhitneyu

Tags: python, scipy, apply

As stated in the title, I ran into a weird situation when estimating `stats.mannwhitneyu` from `scipy`.

Toy data and code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

# data 
np.random.seed(0)  

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=['col_1','col_2'])
df['group_l1'] = ['A']*50 + ['B']*50
df['group_l2'] = ['x']*25 + ['y']*25 +   ['x']*25 + ['y']*25
```

As shown in the `test` part, I use the data split by `group_l2` as two samples to feed the test for both `col_1` and `col_2` within each group of `group_l1`, when I use `ttest_ind` as the test:

```
# test

df[['col_1','col_2','group_l1','group_l2']].groupby('group_l1').\
apply(lambda x: stats.ttest_ind(x.groupby('group_l2')[['col_1','col_2']].get_group('x'),
                                x.groupby('group_l2')[['col_1','col_2']].get_group('y'))[1])
```

the result is:

```
group_l1
A     [0.7746267572903867, 0.9459142110158605]
B    [0.7016762873007549, 0.09047806237946462]
```

which is what I want, But when I use `mannwhitneyu`, the result is:

```
df[['col_1','col_2','group_l1','group_l2']].groupby('group_l1').\
    apply(lambda x: stats.mannwhitneyu(x.groupby('group_l2')[['col_1','col_2']].get_group('x'),
                                    x.groupby('group_l2')[['col_1','col_2']].get_group('y'))[1])


group_l1
A    3.412244e-35
B    7.872898e-33
```

Seems like only one column is calculated, anyone knows why would this happen?

Comment: Import numpy and fix the random seed then you have a perfectly reproducible toy example. Other than that: interesting question. I assume that you are aware that a t-test and the MannWhitneyU test different hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I updated the question by fixing the random seed. But I need to say the `perfectly reproducible` example is not that important here as the problem is not with the `exact numbers` but rather a `formating` issue. I do aware that `t-test` and `mannwhitneyu` test different hypotheses. Any thought why the latter gives only one result？

Comment: @JasonGoal do you want both results to be like those in `mannwhitney` output, or like `ttest_ind` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 reasons this is happening, one reason in `ttest_ind()` and one reason in `manwhitneyu()`.

In `ttest_ind()` the signature has `axis=0` as the default here: 
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/41763e3ea532fc0e9305dde87a48ab3b4d14eac8/scipy/stats/stats.py#L5124

then after the docstring, the function calls `_chk2_asarray(a,b,axis)` to make sure the arguments `a,b` are array-like.
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/41763e3ea532fc0e9305dde87a48ab3b4d14eac8/scipy/stats/stats.py#L5220
Now `_chk2_asarray()` get the `axis=0` default which means both `a,b` are passed through `np.asarray()` here:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/41763e3ea532fc0e9305dde87a48ab3b4d14eac8/scipy/stats/stats.py#L235-L237
so everything is fine. However, if instead of the default `axis` argument  in `ttest_ind()` you instead put `axis=None` you would hit the other codepath of 
`_chk2_asarray()` and you'd run through `np.ravel(a)` and similar for `b` argument. This will 'unstack' your arrays and break the grouping. For example, using the data provided in the post:

```
>>> df[['col_1','col_2','group_l1','group_l2']].groupby('group_l1').\
... apply(lambda x: stats.ttest_ind(x.groupby('group_l2')[['col_1','col_2']].get_group('x'),
...                                 x.groupby('group_l2')[['col_1','col_2']].get_group('y'), axis=None)[1])
group_l1
A    0.138643
B    0.942884
dtype: float64
```

Now, in the `mannwhitneyu()` function the data must be ranked to calculate the test statistic. The scipy ranking method works on a single array, using the one in `scipy.stats` called `rankdata()` here is a link tot he source:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/41763e3ea532fc0e9305dde87a48ab3b4d14eac8/scipy/stats/stats.py#L7307
and the array `a` inside the function is immediately `ravel()`-ed here:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/41763e3ea532fc0e9305dde87a48ab3b4d14eac8/scipy/stats/stats.py#L7363
which breaks the structure you have in your pandas dataframe arguments.

The workaround would be to manually separate the two dataframes and run on each dataframe, e.g. a dataframe with:  `col_1`, and a second dataframe with `col_2`. Unless of course you want everything together as results aggregated across both arrays.

I'm not sure there is an easy work around that could be changed in the code to accommodate what you'd like to do. You could always send an inquiry to scipy-dev email list to propose a change, not obvious to me at this time how that would work though. You'd need to do the ranking within each column so this would require a different (or custom) ranking function.

Hopefully this helps you understand what is going on, it isn't obvious what is happening here, it took me a bit of digging.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, it's excellent.  I posted on Github hoping `scipy` developer could add a workaround for `mannwhitneyu()` when the test is needed for each group.

Comment: @JasonGoal yeah, I responded on the scipy github issue as well noting what is happening and linking here when someone decides to pick up the issue. I'm thinking you could do do the ranking in each column/group separately but I'm not sure if there is a ranking function which is group aware like that, if there was I'm guessing that it would be a numpy thing given that the current implementation of `rankdata()` uses `np.argsort`